# DropboxError in SessionsController - create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

I am testing a ruby on rails app on localhost which needs authentication from dropbox.
When it says

> App would like access to the files and folders in your Dropbox.

I click allow. Then I get

> DropboxError in SessionsController#create
>   v1_retired

I have also,

```
    session['access_token'] = access_token
    @db = get_client access_token
    name = @db.account_info['display_name']
    email = @db.account_info['email']
    uid = @db.account_info['uid']
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid('dropbox', user_id) || User.create_with_omniauth(email, uid, name)
```

Where `name = @db.account_info['display_name']` is in red mark is line 24.

file `` app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:24:in `create' ``

```
Parameters:

{"state"=>"vJUckYTI8YJVzdw1L9OA8g==",
 "code"=>"m6ncKLSfo7AAAAAAAAAADOJrqwYitp3Oi2HW8pXc",
 "provider"=>"dropbox"}
```

`sessions_controller.rb`

```
require 'dropbox_sdk'
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def get_auth
    redirect_uri = ENV['db_callback']
    flow = DropboxOAuth2Flow.new( ENV['db_key'], ENV['db_secret'], redirect_uri, session, :dropbox_auth_csrf_token)
  end
  def new
     auth_url = get_auth.start
     redirect_to auth_url
  end
  def index
    if session['access_token'] != ''
      @user = get_dropbox_client.account_info['display_name']
    end
  end
  def create     
    code = params[:code]
    begin
      access_token, user_id, url_state = get_auth.finish(params)
    rescue Exception
    end
    session['access_token'] = access_token
    @db = get_client access_token
    name = @db.account_info['display_name']
    email = @db.account_info['email']
    uid = @db.account_info['uid']
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid('dropbox', user_id) || User.create_with_omniauth(email, uid, name)     
    session[:user_id] = uid
    session[:access_token] = access_token
    session[:user_name] = name
    user.access_token = access_token
    user.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end
  def destroy
    session.clear
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

routs.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
  match '/', to: 'sites#load', constraints: { subdomain: /.+/ }, via: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete]
  root 'sites#index'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/auth/dropbox', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/*req', to: 'sites#load', constraints: { subdomain: /.+/ }, via: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete]
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
  get '/source', to: 'pages#source'
  get '/pricing', to: 'pages#pricing'
  get '/admin', to: 'pages#admin'
  get '/webhook', to: 'webhook#challenge'
  post '/webhook', to: 'webhook#post'
  post "/versions/:id/revert", to: "versions#revert", as: "revert_version"
  resources :sites, path: '' 
end
```

I have `gem 'dropbox-sdk'` in my gemfile and application_controller.rb is

```
require 'dropbox_sdk'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def get_client at
    return DropboxClient.new(at)
  end

  def current_user
    User.find_by( access_token: session['access_token'] )
  end

end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'dropbox-sdk' 
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'pry'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'dalli'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

How to change file application_controller.rb according to dropbox_api

Comment: The dropbox v1 api [is depreciated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You need to change to the v2 api.

Comment: I created app with api key and secret today. I think I created v2 api. Still it shows `v1 retired`. I have this url `http://localhost:3000/auth/dropbox/callback?state=LnT%2FHfMAyjtsa8ZIJZcQ%3D%3D&code=S6EYwSozTeAAAAAAAAAAXDlmQeg_Lf8dlRtd9FItw`

Comment: did you use gem for api call? if yes you could share your gemfile/gem

Answer (score 0):

because dropbox api V1 is already [retired](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/) you need to upgrade your api

here follow this [Dropbox API v1 → v2 Migration guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide)

and if you using gemfile to connect to the api,

the official dropbox api wrapper (dropbox-sdk-ruby) or `gem 'dropbox-sdk'`

is deprecated [see their doc](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-ruby)

you could use this 3rd party api wrapper instead [dropbox_api](https://github.com/Jesus/dropbox_api)

Comment: I created app with api key and secret today. I think I created v2 api. Still it shows `v1 retired`. I have updated my question, please check codes.

Comment: did you use this gemfile? `dropbox-sdk-ruby` if yes then its deprecated you could try this gemfile https://github.com/Jesus/dropbox_api

Comment: I used `gem 'dropbox-sdk' `. please check my question again. How to change my related file application_controller.rb

Comment: see my updated answer that gem is deprecated you need to change it.

Comment: I changed it and bundle installed, but there is `require 'dropbox_sdk' `in application_controller.rb and session_controller.rb. These file codes are in my question. I changed just that lines to `dropbox_api`. I think there is more code changes according to change dropbox_api. When I go to `http://localhost:3000/auth/dropbox` I get `uninitialized constant SessionsController::DropboxOAuth2Flow` line is `flow = DropboxOAuth2Flow.new( ENV['db_key'], ENV['db_secret'], redirect_uri, session, :dropbox_auth_csrf_token)` in session_controller.rb.

Comment: ah I see its hard because you are not a developer. you cannot just change the gem you also need to change the whole implementation, read and follow the doc, if you still can't then you need to find proper assistance from a developer.